# How do I send and/or Receive Colors as argument in Flutter

Tags: flutter

here is the declaration of 'colour' `final Colors colour;`

this is the method/constructor where I will be receiving a color from my **main.dart**

```
MyCardState(
    myQuestion: myQuestion,
    myColor: colour,
    opA: myOptionA,
    opB: myOptionB
  )
```

But I have no idea how to send a color from my **main.dart**. I tried `colour: Colors.cyan` but it won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the class Color, in singular:

```
class MyCardState {
  final Color color;

  MyCardState({this.color});
}
```

Also, keep in mind that some colors in `Colors.*` are instances of MaterialColor and not Color.

Comment: thanks for the info I appreciate it but how should I send a color that I'll receive in the method/constructor 'MyCardState' from main

I would appreciate it if you could tell me with an example.

Comment: In my example, you can pass a color like : MyCardState(color:  Colors.red);

Comment: In my case I'm passing the main color like `Colors.red` to child widget. Is it possible to access that color `shades` inside child widget?. for example `color[50]` ?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved I was supposed to use `final Color colour` instead of `final Colors colour`